# delete external text file from .swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a swf file (game file) which reads the content of external text file which I have created. This swf file will not be used in any browser. It's for windows only. I was wondering if I can delete or update that text file after I read it's content without using air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, I'm not sure what exactly you wanted to know. But if I understood you correctly:

You cannot delete files from the filesystem in the through Flash Player, but you can however delete it from SWF file's memory.

Deleting from the file system (basically like putting into trash) is something that only AIR can help you with.
Deleting from memory would mean to remove all the listeners from URLLoader or Loader object instance and setting it to `null`.

You cannot write the file with Flash player to edit it's content (update), but you can load it again and check if anything changed in that file's content that also would be considered as updating.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Air looks like only option. Can you give me the code to do it with air ?

Comment: Basically you're interested in the File and FileStream classes. Read about the http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html

There are tons of tutorials and examples with how to use these classes to Create new files, Edit and Delete files.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do that without air. but you can use an external application using fscommand().

or you can use Multimedia Zinc